# TV doesn't work with custom resolution

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, display-resolution, amd-graphics, tv

I use to run Windows 10 on my computer and use my TV as an extended screen with resolution 1776x1000. I installed kubuntu 20.04 yesterday and I can't get it to work properly with my TV. I didn't see the 1776x1000 on the mode list and I tried to add it:

```
cvt 1776 1000
xrandr --newmode "1776x1000_60.00" ... (copied from the previous output)
xrandr --addmode DVI-0 "1776x1000_60.00"
xrandr --output DVI-0 --mode "1776x1000_60.00"
```

And the TV screen went blue with the text "unusable mode".

I have an old Samsung tv I don't know much about. My video card is ATI Radeon HD 6770.

I still use Windows 10 on my laptop, when I connect it to my TV it uses resolution 1768x992. I tried this resolution too and got the same result. How can I fix this?